# Each proper ideal is a product of prime ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$R$ is a commutative ring with unity.

If $R$ is P.I.D. I want to show that each of its proper ideal is written as a product of prime ideals.

$$$$

Since $R$ is a P.I.D. every ideal is a prime ideal, right?

So, how can it be that each proper ideal is a product of prime ideals?

Comment: What about $\mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Are all its proper ideals a product of prime ideals? So, aren't all its ideals prime ideals? @CaptainLama

Comment: All ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$ are of the form $(n)$ for some $n\in \mathbb{Z}$. Is the ideal $(n)$ always prime ?

Comment: Every ideal in a PID is *principal* ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a PID, $R$, every ideal is principal. That is every ideal is of the form $(a)$ for some $a \in R$.

So let $(a)$ be a proper ideal in $R$. PIDs are unique factorization domains, so we can write $a = p_1p_2 \cdots p_n$ for some prime/irreducible elements $p_1,p_2,\dots, p_n \in R$. The ideals $P_i = (p_i)$ are prime ideals.

Claim: $(a) = P_1P_2\dots P_n$.

If $r \in (a)$, then $r = sa = s p_1p_2 \cdots p_n$ for some $s \in R$. But then $$r = s p_1p_2 \cdots p_n \in P_1P_2\dots P_n.$$ Therefore $(a) \subseteq P_1P_2\dots P_n$.

If $r \in P_1P_2\dots P_n$, $\exists s \in R$ and $\exists p_i' \in P_i$ for $i= 1,\dots,n$ such that $r = sp_1'p_2'\dots p_n'$. But since $p_i' \in P_i = (p_i)$, $\exists t_i \in R$ such that $p_i'=t_ip_i$. Hence
$$  r = s(t_1\dots t_n)(p_1\dots p_n) = s(t_1\dots t_n)a \in (a).$$
Therefore $P_1P_2\dots P_n \subseteq (a)$.

And thus $(a) = P_1P_2\dots P_n$.

Comment: Should one stress that $r\in\langle a\rangle\Rightarrow\exists s\in R, r=sa$ is true due to $R$ having a unity? Because $a\in\langle a\rangle\Rightarrow\exists s_a\in R, a=s_aa\Rightarrow \exists s_a\in R, (1-s_a)a=0$?

Comment: Also, I think $r\in P_1P_2\cdots P_n$ isn't necessarily of the form $r=sp_1'p_2'\cdots p_n'$ for some $s\in R$ and $p_i'\in P_i,i=1,\ldots,n.$  The product $P_1P_2\cdots P_n$ is just generated by the products $x_1x_2\cdots x_n,$ where $x_i\in P_i,i=1,\ldots,n$ so maybe stress that it is sufficient to prove the generators of $P_1P_2\cdots P_n$ are contained in $(a)$?